# Из-за чего ошибка в PHP-скрипте?

Tags: php

```
function compress_png($path_to_png_file, $max_quality = 90)
{
    if (!file_exists($path_to_png_file)) {
        throw new Exception("File does not exist: $path_to_png_file"); // ругается на эту строку
    }
   $min_quality = 60;
   $compressed_png_content = shell_exec("/home/tmp/pngquant 2>&1 --quality=$min_quality-$max_quality - < ".escapeshellarg($path_to_png_file));

    if (!$compressed_png_content) {
        echo "0";
    }

return $compressed_png_content;
}
```

Работал код до вчера, и вдруг перестал работать, апач перезагружал, сервер перезагружал и ничего.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File does not exist: ./pic/zombie-smashdown-dead-warrior481.png' in /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/sql.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/sql.php(122): compress_png('./pic/zombi...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/sql.php on line 10
```

А это вот 122 строка:

```
$path_to_uncompressed_file = './pic/'.p($_POST['title']).$rand_img.'.png';
$path_to_compressed_file = './pic/'.p($_POST['title']).'_'.$rand_img.'.png';
file_put_contents($path_to_compressed_file, compress_png($path_to_uncompressed_file)); // 122 stkora
unlink($path_to_uncompressed_file);
```

Comment: Четко написано какого файла нет. Проверяйте наличие указанного файла.

Comment: это я вижу, но, этот же код вчера еще работал, его никто не трогал и тут он уже не работает...

Comment: А ничего что вчера файл мог быть, а сегодня мог не быть? Работоспособность кода зависит в данном случае и от внешних факторов.

Comment: Может кто-то удалил или перенес файлы? Или побилась файловая система и файлов не стало.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте проверку на существование файла ([file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-exists.php))  перед функцией `file_put_contents()`:

```
if (file_exists($path_to_uncompressed_file)) {
    file_put_contents($path_to_compressed_file, compress_png($path_to_uncompressed_file));
    unlink($path_to_uncompressed_file);
}
```

И не ленитесь читать ошибки и документацию. Иначе вам не выжить в ИТ.

### UPD

Не заметил код функции `compress_png()` в начале. Вам достаточно отловить [исключение](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php) через `try{} catch(){}`:

```
$path_to_uncompressed_file = './pic/'.p($_POST['title']).$rand_img.'.png';
$path_to_compressed_file = './pic/'.p($_POST['title']).'_'.$rand_img.'.png';
try {
    file_put_contents($path_to_compressed_file, compress_png($path_to_uncompressed_file)); // 122 stkora
    unlink($path_to_uncompressed_file);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // что-то пошло не так. Скорее всего файл не существует. Текст ошибки в $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: появилось очень и очень много ошибок

Comment: @RomanVulchyn иногда первая ошибка влечет за собой остальные, исправьте первую и тестируйте дальше